# Edit Text in SharePoint Form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

[image]Im new to SharePoint and have been asked to update some text on a form in SharePoint. I can’t figure out how to select and make the changes. When I select the web part that contains the form textboxes, buttons etc, there does not seem to be a way to select and edit the text. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I should try?

Comment: How was the form customized? The answer depends on whether it's out of the box, SharePoint Designer, InfoPath, inline script, etc. If you don't know, maybe share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your SharePoint site using SharePoint designer and do all the customization needed there.

Or you can add a content editor web part and inside its content just add a `<script>` tag and add some JavaScript that get the label you want to change and edit its content